# Iterate through threads run via ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and when I create a `Process` which implements `Runnable` I run it via: `executor.execute(process)`.

Now, before calling `execute` I want to check one field from `Process` object and compare it with ALL other **currently running** processes, executed by my `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. How I can do that, not generating a concurrent problem?

Code:

```
public class MyApp {

   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

   //...

   public void runProcesses {
       Process firstone = new Process(1);
       Process nextOne = new Process(1);


       // iterate through all processes started via executor and currently running,
       // verify if there is any process.getX() == 1, if not run it

       executor.execute(firstone );

       //wait till firstone will end becouse have the same value of X
       executor.execute(nextOne); // this cant be perform until the first one will end
   }
}

public class Process {
    private int x;

    //...

    public Process (int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getX(){
         return this.x;
    }

}
```

I was thinking about createing simple `Set` of process started and add new one to it. But I have problem how to determine is it still running and remove it from set when it is done. So now I'm thinking about iterating through running threads, but completly dunno how.

Comment: "... not generating a concurrent problem" - not at all. You'll always have to deal with concurrency issues when doing this kind of check. What is that check actually checking? Perhaps you can do it another way?

Comment: It is checking exacly what I mentioned. In other words, there can't be 2 processes with the same value of field x. I have added more code to ilustrate whant i need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your initial idea is pretty good and can be made to work with not too much code.
It will require some tinkering in order to decouple "is a `Runnable` for this value already running" from "execute this `Runnable`", but here's a rough illustration that doesn't take care about that:

- Implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Process`, so that instances can safely be used in unordered sets and maps.
- Create a `ConcurrentMap<Process, Boolean>`

  - You won't be using `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Process, Boolean>)` because you'd want to use the map's `putIfAbsent()` method.
- Try to add in it using `putIfAbsent()` each `Process` that you will be submitting and bail if the returned value is not `null`.

  - A non-`null` return value means that there's already an equivalent `Process` in the map (and therefore being processed).
  - The trivial and not very clean solution will be to inject a reference to the map in each `Process` instance and have `putIfAbsent(this, true)` as the first thing you do in your `run()` method.
- Remove from it each `Process` that has finished processing.

  - The trivial and not very clean solution will be inject a reference to the map in each `Process` instance and have `remove(this)` as the last thing you do in your `run()` method.
  - Other solutions can have `Process` implement `Callable` and return its unique value as a result, so that it can be removed from the map, or use `CompletableFuture` and its `thenAccept()` callback.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/kfYr9Sjm) a sample that illustrates the trivial and not very clean solution described above (code too long to paste directly here).

Comment: Sounds perfect for me, i will definitely give it a try.

Comment: However. shouldn't it be a `ConcurrentMap<Integer, Boolean>`? becouse we want to compare X field (integer type). Or my implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` should be focused on only X field?

Comment: "wait till firstone will end" is not fulfilled, right?

Comment: @hahn Yes, wait untill firstone will end its processing

Answer (score 2):

Though `@Dimitar` provided very good solution for solving this problem I want to make an addition with another approach.

Having your requirements, it seems like you need to keep all submitted `Process`es, slicing them by `x` into separate queues and executing processes in queues one by one.

`API` of `ThreadPoolExecutor` empowers to enhance behaviour of Executor and I came to the following implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2,
        0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()) {

    private final ConcurrentMap<Integer, Queue<Runnable>> processes = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        if (command instanceof Process) {
            int id = ((Process) command).getX();
            Queue<Runnable> t = new ArrayDeque<>();
            Queue<Runnable> queue = this.processes.putIfAbsent(id, t);
            if (queue == null) {
                queue = t;
            }
            synchronized (queue) {
                queue.add(command);
                if (!processes.containsKey(id)) {
                    processes.put(id, queue);
                }
                if (queue.size() == 1) {
                    super.execute(queue.peek()); // removal of current process would be done in #afterExecute
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.execute(command);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        if (r instanceof Process) {
            int id = ((Process) r).getX();
            Queue<Runnable> queue = this.processes.get(id);
            synchronized (queue) {
                queue.poll(); // remove completed prev process
                Runnable nextProcess = queue.peek(); // retrieve next process
                if (nextProcess != null) {
                    super.execute(nextProcess);
                } else {
                    this.processes.remove(id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```